# C Language FILE I/O about fscanf

Tags: c, file-io

I was wondering if you could help me with this problem. this code contain void for updating a variable in a `.txt` file. but, sometimes the program wouldn't or couldn't read the second `while(fscanf)`. I don't know what is the problem because sometimes it will read it and sometimes it won't. this occurs not only after I change something in the code but even if I don't change it, but the strange thing is that the program would always read the first `while(fscanf)`. could you point out the the problem?

```
    void editData(){
    system("cls");
    int idKey;
    fdata = fopen("fileObat.txt", "r");
    fdnew = fopen("fileObatNew.txt", "w+");
    
    while(fscanf(fdata, "%d %s %s %d %d %s %s\n", &dO.id, dO.nama, dO.noRak, &dO.stok, &dO.harga, dO.tglProd, dO.tglEx)!=EOF){
        printf("%d %s %s %d %d %s %s\n", dO.id, dO.nama, dO.noRak, dO.stok, dO.harga, dO.tglProd, dO.tglEx);
    }
    printf("\nMasukan id obat yang akan diubah: ");
    scanf("%d", &idKey);
    
    while(fscanf(fdata, "%d %s %s %d %d %s %s\n", &dO.id, dO.nama, dO.noRak, &dO.stok, &dO.harga, dO.tglProd, dO.tglEx)!=EOF){
        if(idKey==dO.id){
            printf("=============================\n");
            printf("===== Pilihan Perubahan =====\n");
            printf("=============================\n");
            printf("1. edit stok\n");
            printf("2. edit harga\n");
            printf("3. edit no.rak\n");
            printf("pilihan: ");
            scanf("%d", &pilih);
            switch(pilih){
                case 1:
                    printf("%d %s %s %d %d %s %s\n\n", dO.id, dO.nama, dO.noRak, dO.stok, dO.harga, dO.tglProd, dO.tglEx);
                    printf("stok: ");
                    scanf("%d", &eDO.stok);
                    fprintf(fdnew, "%d %s %s %d %d %s %s\n", dO.id, dO.nama, dO.noRak, eDO.stok, dO.harga, dO.tglProd, dO.tglEx);
                    printf("\n%d %s %s %d %d %s %s\n", dO.id, dO.nama, dO.noRak, eDO.stok, dO.harga, dO.tglProd, dO.tglEx);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    printf("%d %s %s %d %d %s %s\n\n", dO.id, dO.nama, dO.noRak, dO.stok, dO.harga, dO.tglProd, dO.tglEx);
                    printf("harga: ");
                    scanf("%d", &eDO.harga);
                    fprintf(fdnew, "%d %s %s %d %d %s %s\n", dO.id, dO.nama, dO.noRak, dO.stok, eDO.harga, dO.tglProd, dO.tglEx);
                    printf("\n%d %s %s %d %d %s %s\n", dO.id, dO.nama, dO.noRak, dO.stok, eDO.harga, dO.tglProd, dO.tglEx);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    printf("%d %s %s %d %d %s %s\n\n", dO.id, dO.nama, dO.noRak, dO.stok, dO.harga, dO.tglProd, dO.tglEx);
                    printf("No.Rak: ");
                    scanf("%d", eDO.noRak);
                    fprintf(fdnew, "%d %s %s %d %d %s %s\n", dO.id, dO.nama, eDO.noRak, dO.stok, dO.harga, dO.tglProd, dO.tglEx);
                    printf("\n%d %s %s %d %d %s %s\n", dO.id, dO.nama, eDO.noRak, dO.stok, dO.harga, dO.tglProd, dO.tglEx);
                    break;
                /*default:
                    printf("Masukan salah:");
                    break;*/
            }
        }else{
            fprintf(fdnew, "%d %s %s %d %d %s %s\n", dO.id, dO.nama, dO.noRak, dO.stok, dO.harga, dO.tglProd, dO.tglEx);
        }
    }
    fclose(fdata);
    fclose(fdnew);
    
    printf("success\n");
    remove("fileObat.txt");
    rename("fileObatNew.txt", "fileObat.txt");
    
    //system("cls");
    printf("9. Kembali ke kelola obat\n");
    printf("0. keluar\n");
    scanf("%d", &pilih);
    switch (pilih){
        case 9:
            kelolaObat();
            break;
        case 0:
            break;
        default:
            printf("Masukan anda salah!");
            getch();
    }
};
```

Comment: What are you doing between the first and second `while ... != EOF` loops that would in any way 'reset' the `fdata` FP so that it won't remain at end-of-file after the first loop?

Comment: @postfm - complete code and sample "fileObat.txt" missing

Comment: Please remove the `\n` newline from `fscanf()` format strings. It can make the input stall. The format specifiers you use all remove whitespace automatically, anyway.

Comment: You should also check the return value from `fscanf()` against the number of conversion you expect, not `EOF`. If there were fewer than expected successful conversions, that won't be picked up by your check.

Comment: *never* use `"%s"` in a scanf format string.  It is no better than `gets`.  You must include a maximum field width which is no greater than 1 less than the size of the corresponding buffer.